# Low storage and Play Store problems after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

After I did a factory reset (twice; once through settings, once through recovery mode by clearing eMMC), I got a "low storage space" error. I can't get rid out of it - tried clearing cache and uninstalling every pre-installed app I could.

It's a generic Android device from Amazon (China) for $40, so of course, it reports tons of free space.

The main problem is that I can't install any apps. Google Play doesn't update. From the old store, I can't install anything, error 504. Installation of .apk's fails too, for an unknown reason.

Something weird happens that I can't understand: after a while, when I try to open Google Play Store, it says "app isn't installed". More curiously, restarting fixes the issue!

TL;DR I want to be able to at least install apps. The main issue is low storage. Factory reset doesn't work.

Comment: Where does internal storage point? Also, what Android version? Oops, 2019. Muh bad

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SD card slot you could format a storage card to the phone and configure that card to be your default for app storage. That could give you a better platform to start downloading the apps to your phone.